# Function to count duplicate characters in a string

Tags: javascript, object, duplicates

I am trying to write a function which finds all unique characters in a provided string.

I'd like the function to return the results in the following format:

```
removeDuplicates('th#elex_ash?') -> {unique: 'aehlstx', duplicates: 2}
```

So far I have come up with the following attempted solution:

```
function removeDuplicates(str){
    var unique ="";
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        if(unique.indexOf(str[i]) == -1){
            unique += str[i];
        }
    }
    unique = unique.replace(/[&\/\\#,_+()$~%.'":*?<>]/g, '');
    return unique.split('').sort().join('');




}

console.log(removeDuplicates('aaabbbac'));
console.log(removeDuplicates('a'));
console.log(removeDuplicates('th#elex_ash?'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing for an environment where you can use newer javascript features. [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) makes this a little easier since it will enforce uniqueness among the contents. You can also compare the lengths of the cleaned string with the uniques to find the duplicate count

For example:

```js
function removeDuplicates(str){
    str = str.replace(/[&\/\\#,_+()$~%.'":*?<>]/g, '')
    let unique = Array.from(new Set(str))
                 .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
                 .join('')
    
    let duplicates = str.length - unique.length
    return {unique, duplicates}
}

console.log(removeDuplicates("th#elex_ash?"))
```

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts — I knew that and just wasn't thinking. I'll edit…

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicates(str) {
    var returnObject = {
        unique : "",
        duplicates : 0
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if (returnObject.unique.indexOf(str[i]) < 0) {
            returnObject.unique += str[i];
        } else {
            returnObject.duplicates++;
        }
    }

    returnObject.unique = returnObject.unique.replace(/[&\/\\#,_+()$~%.'":*?<>]/g, '');
    returnObject.unique = returnObject.unique.split('').sort().join('');

    return returnObject;
}

console.log(removeDuplicates('aaabbbac'));
console.log(removeDuplicates('a'));
console.log(removeDuplicates('th#elex_ash?'));
```

Comment: Thanks @pseudobbs, exactly what i was looking to do

Comment: No problem!  Can you mark as correct or upvote?  I'm new on SO and trying to build reputation

Comment: Still having issues

Comment: Return object should have a 'uniques' string property.

 Return object should have a 'duplicates' number property.
 'uniques' should be 'aehlstx'

Comment: so change the name of the string property from `unique` to `uniques`

Answer (score 0):

You are very close!

An object can be returned in Javascript just like anything else; for instance, to return the format you were asking for, simply do the following:

```
return {
    unique: unique,
    duplicates: duplicates
}
```

Notice how your variable names are the same as your property keys? You can use a shorthand notation by simply writing `unique` and `duplicates`, rather than `unique: unique` and `duplicates: duplicates`.

---

You're not keeping a count of duplicates. To do so, simply add an `else` block to your `if(unique.indexOf(str[i]) == -1)` conditional, which should only be reached when a character is indeed a duplicate, and increment a counter - lets name it `duplicates`.

---

**Complete Solution**

```js
function removeDuplicates(str) {
  var unique = "";
  var duplicates = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (unique.indexOf(str[i]) == -1) {
      unique += str[i];
    } else {
      duplicates++;
    }
  }
  unique = unique.replace(/[&\/\\#,_+()$~%.'":*?<>]/g, '').split('').sort().join('')

  return {
    unique,
    duplicates
  }
}


const testString = 'th#elex_ash?';
const expectedOutput = {
  unique: 'aehlstx',
  duplicates: 2
};

console.log(removeDuplicates(testString));
```